# How can i get all distinct values of a html 5 custom attribute in a faster way

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML document with a dynamic number of DIVs. Each DIV represents information about something, and a HTML 5 custom attribute in the DIV tag represents the ETA (estimated time of arrival).

I want to style the divs (the background) to visually separate the ETAs. So i want to give the ETAs alternating colors (first found ETA red, second found ETA yellow, 3rd found ETA red again, etc)

Examples of ETAS possible:

1,2,3,4

1,3,5,6

3,5,8,9

The problem is that one ETA can occur multiple times

I have been searching for how to do this, but the only thing I came up with is an each loop. I am looking for a faster and simpler method, if at all possible.

```html
<div class="someclass" data-eta="1"> </div>
<div class="someotherclassclass"> </div>
<div class="someclass" data-eta="2"> </div>
<div class="someclass" data-eta="2"> </div>
<div class="someclass" data-eta="4"> </div>
<div class="someclass" data-eta="7"> </div>
```

JS/jquery:

```
var some_tbl=$('.someclass');
// Get the ETA's
incs_tbl.each(function(i,e) { eta_tbl.push($(e).data('eta')); });       
eta_tbl=new Set(eta_tbl);
// Now alternate the backgrounds
eta_tbl.forEach(function(i,e)
{
  if (i % 2 == 0) { tmp='yellow'; } else { tmp='red'; };
  $('.someclass[data-eta='+e+']').css({'background-color': tmp});           
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the problem with your existing code?

Comment: I don’t understand exactly what you’re trying to accomplish here – could you please edit your question to show what the intended styling should be? Would you want the five `div.someclass`es in your example here to be styled as _grey, lightgrey, grey, lightgrey, grey_ (in that order)? Or do you want _grey, lightgrey, lightgrey, grey, lightgrey_? I don’t understand why you’re using modulo 2 – surely your current function would yield _grey, lightgrey, lightgrey, lightgrey, grey_ – is that the styling you’re after (and if so, what is the logic behind it)?

Comment: (I’m ignoring the fact that you first say grey and lightgrey, but then use yellow and red in your jQuery, but that doesn’t help with the clarity.)

Comment: @eddie: not so much a problem, but ore an itch that the code isn;t efficient. I was thinking it could be faster, with less code

Comment: @janus you are right, edited the question to have matching colors in the text. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$('.someclass').each(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color': $(this).data().eta % 2 == 0? 'yellow' : 'red'});
});
```

EDIT:

If you are not absolutely sure that data-eta exists and it is a number in all the elements with the class someclass, you must check it. For example:

```
$('.someclass').each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data();
    if (data && !isNaN(data.eta)) $(this).css({'background-color': data.eta % 2 == 0? 'yellow' : 'red'});
});
```

Comment: this seems to be the best answer for now. I cannot prevent an .exch() I think, and your answer is more elegant then my code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery "filter" method? :

```
$('.someclass').filter(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-color': $(this).data().eta % 2 == 0 ? 'yellow' : 'red'});
});
```